# Design a simple cache manager in nodejs to manage file on disk

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, lru

My server receives an input data and generate an output file. I need to cache this output file, when an user requests input again, server will return output file instantly. The cache manager need:

- Entry: inputId -> path to processed file (cached file)
- Many server processes can set and get cache entries at the same time
- Limit total size of cached file, remove old cached files if disk is full
- Cached files expire and are removed after some time. If cache hit then reset expire time of cached file.
- Server processes can crash, or computer can shutdown anytime. Cache manager can discard incorrect data but keep valid cached file.

Now, I'm using redis as LRU cache.

- inputId -> filePath with expire time
- A Sorted Set: inputId -> last access time of file
- Write 3 lua scripts to setCache(inputId, filePath), getCache(inputId), removeCache(inputId)
- Periodically check disk space to remove least recently used files.
- Listen to event a redis key expires to remove file cache

In general, I feel my implementation is not strong enough to handle processes/computer restart/crash. I intend to save cache index into databases.
I need some comments about my design. Do I need to reinventing the wheel ? (stackoverflow doesn't allow seeking about libraries or documents)

Comment: Are the lua script running with the redis server with LOAD and EVAL?

Comment: Yes. redis client uses command load and eval to run lua scripts in redis server.